# Blender obj/fbx export does not include all used materials

Tags: modeling, materials

I started to use Blender yesterday but I struggle to export my object with the right materials.
I would like to get the same/similar texture in a 3D Model so that I can open it up in for instance unity again.

I used three different materials for my object but two of them don't get into the fbx or obj/mtl file (even though i checked all the check-boxes below during the export).

[image: check boxes]

**The two materials that are missing:**

1.) Rough silver surface created with a displacement node:

[image]

2.) Horizontal lines on a black surface:

[image]

If I open the .blend file it looks like this: (this is how it should look like)

[image]

But if I export it (as .obj + .mtl) in blender and import it again (also in blender) it looks like this:

[image]